# My run console disapear in Intellij

Tags: intellij-idea, console

I work on Intellij but I don't know where my Run console is gone.
If I open intellij on another computer, I can add the Run console like this:

[image]

I dont find Run in this panel on the first computer'Intellij and in View -> Tool Windos -> Run is shaded (like below):

[image]

Thank you

Comment: Hum, simply run your project via the `Run` menu and the console will appear automatically (it's hidden until you actually run something).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**View->Tool Windows->Terminal**, can this help?

Comment: Thanks for your answer, the button is shaded so I update my question with your remark

Comment: @a.moussa You should promise compilation is right and there is a configuration(main function) in your project/.java file.  After that, you can run it.